# When equations are written the describe quantum experiments, does the equation necessarily include the set up conditions of the subatomic particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What I am wondering is e.g. when an experiment is done on the LHC, this involves colliding particles traveling in opposite directions, at a certain speed and one might assume angular momentum. The experiment is conducted to examine the consequences of the collision of the particles.

So the part of the experiment that involves getting the particles to be collided, to the desired physical states prior to the collision, is integral to the equation of the entire experiment?

It would be good to know whether this is correct or not with some certainty.

Comment: Welcome to the Physics stack exchange! Just a question: What do you mean with "is integral to the equation of the entire experiment" ?

Comment: Without initial conditions you can't get any specific predictions. So at least the initial conditions must be included in the system of equations to solve. But indeed, the full answer depends on what you mean by "being integral to the equation".

Comment: By integral, I meant that removing that part of the equation covering the initial conditions, renders the experiment unable to be conducted.

Comment: I suppose you have already answered my question, but it is important. It is the strict end, if you like, of the observer effect. Rather than speculate, I'm just wanting to ensure a minimum point that all agree on.